# captcha code not working

Tags: php, html, captcha

I have designed the comments box for getting comments. Instead of using captcha plugins, i have prepared custom captcha with 5 digit number.  When I submit the details, still I getting error page. I have checked various sites in Google but could not find the correct answer.

1. comments.html - Comment box for comments
2. captcha.php  - Custom captcha with 5 digit code
3. submit.php  - for processing the code
4. error.html - error page  for wrong entry
5. thank.html - Page on submitting successful

I am unable to sort-out where the mistake is. Kindly help me in this regards.
The sources codes of comments.html and submit.php is given below.

=========COMMENTS.HTML==============

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post"> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> <br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" /> <br>
Comments:  <textarea  name="coments" />  <br>
Enter Captcha <img src="captcha.php"><input type="text" name="vercode" /> <br>
<input type="submit" name='submit'  onclick="show_confirm()" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

=============SUBMIT.PHP=================

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if ($_POST["vercode"] != $_SESSION["vercode"] OR $_SESSION["vercode"]=='') 
       {
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    header('Location: error.html');
    exit;
       }
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(empty($name) || empty($email)||empty($comments)) 
    {
    header('Location:error.html');
    exit;
    }
    if(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_POST[email]))  
   {
    header('Location:error.html');
    exit;
    }
    $email_from = 'info@xxxxx.com';
$email_subject = "CONTACT FORM";

$email_body="============================\n".
"FULL NAME: $name\n".
"EMAIL-ID:   $email\n".
"COMMENTS:     $comments\n".

$to = "info2@xxxxx.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank.html');
?>
```

Comment: You need `session_start()` at the very top of your submit.php

Comment: Sir, the session_start(); is there for both submit.php and cptcha.php. But each time, it is showing error page only.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
session_start()
```

at the very top of your `submit.php`, that starts or resume your `session` so that you can access `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the form was submitted first, then process the code. Example:

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // process stuff }

You didn't show what specific error you get, so I'm just going to link you to this simple PHP-GD captcha that I have used previously in some projects and works like a charm. Is really simple and easy to implement.

[Simple PHP-GD captcha image](http://www.php-help.ro/php-tutorials/simple-php-gd-capcha-image/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may have something to do with your regex verification always returning false.

You may want to test if the rule you set is correct. Also, I have read on php.net that eregi() is now obsolete in 5.3.0, so maybe use preg_match()  with PCRE_CASELESS flag instead ?